# Assert a value is one from a set of acceptable values

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest

I have written test method to check scenario.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Return_CheckJUNK_GetComperatorForConditions()
{
    // Arrange 
    string whereClause = "This is the Test String.";
    string conditionLeft = "This is";
    string conditionRight = "Test String.";
    object[] args = new object[3] { whereClause, conditionLeft, conditionRight };

    // Act 
    PrivateObject objPrivate = new PrivateObject(typeof(ManageConfigurations));
    var result = (string)objPrivate.Invoke("GetComperatorForConditions", args);

    // Assert 
    object[] arg = new object[2] { "AND", "OR" };
    Assert.AreEqual(arg, result);
}
```

> I want to check multiple condition that result is either 'AND' or 'OR'.

I know this line has some error that it is not proper way to compare to options

```
object[] arg = new object[2] { "AND", "OR" };
Assert.AreEqual(arg, result);
```

**Error:**

```
Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<System.Object[ (System.Object[])>. Actual:<the (System.String)>.
```

Comment: You can always use `Assert.IsTrue()` with an arbitrary boolean expression.

Comment: You want to check that `result == "AND" || result == "OR"`?

Comment: Why don't you read [ask] and explain what the actual value of `result` is and why you want to compare that to an array of two strings? Also, why can one method call potentially yield two different values? Is there a random component involved? You have another problem altogether, because the string "the" will never equal either "AND" nor "OR".  Edit: people please don't upvote non-repro/non-[mcve] questions.

Comment: Please clarify if you want to test for both or either values?

Comment: I want to check either value. result == "AND" || result == "OR"

Comment: You could do something like Assert.IsTrue(arg.Contains(result)); if you know that result will always be either "OR", "AND" or something else. But I agree with Paul Kertscher's comment below about making tests definitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over complicated. Why not this?

```
object[] arg = new object[2] { "AND", "OR" };
Assert.AreEqual(arg[0] == result || arg[1] == result, true);
```

Or even simpler (thanks to Marc Gravell):

```
Assert.IsTrue(result == "AND" || result == "OR");
```

Or generic approach for collection of values using LINQ:

```
object[] arg = new object[2] { "AND", "OR" };
Assert.IsTrue(arg.Any(x => x == result));
```

If you are too lazy to do this each time write extension method which iterates though your collection comparing values with result.

Comment: by the time you've hard-coded indices, you might as well have just used `Assert.IsTrue(result == "AND" || result == "OR");`

Comment: Can't he just have multiple `Assert.IsTrue()` in his method? checking the conditions one by one

Comment: @MarcGravell found even nicer solution with LINQ

Answer (score 5):

You can use `CollectionAssert.Contains()` to test that a collection contains a value. Although it inverts the roles of values in your test, it will cover the condition with a single statement:

```
CollectionAssert.Contains(new [] { "AND", "OR" }, result);
```

Comment: They want to check if it's either value, which this statement does.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to check multiple condition that result is either 'AND' or 'OR'.

This sounds like a bad idea to me. Units and unit tests should be written in a way that the expected outcome is definite. Think about formulating your tests in a way that you can for example do (NUnit-esque, but to make the point)

```
[TestCase("This is the Test string.", "This is", "Test string.", "AND")]
[TestCase("This is the Test string.", "This is", "FooBar", "OR")]
public void Return_CheckJUNK_GetComperatorForConditions(string whereClause, string conditionLeft, string conditionRight, string expectedComparator)
{
    var args = new object[] { whereClause, conditionLeft, conditionRight };

    var objPrivate = new PrivateObject(typeof(ManageConfigurations));
    var result = (string)objPrivate.Invoke("GetComperatorForConditions", args);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedComparator, result);
}
```

If the outcome depends on a configuration, either fix the configuration for your tests, *or better* make a test per configuration.